# Sorting Icons with dataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables

Is there a way with dataTables to have it not show the sort icons for columns containing either an empty column heading or the words Edit or Delete.

As of right now I'm using this:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
    { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [ 4,5 ] 
}
```

Which works for 4,5 because those are the Edit and Delete columns but I"m thinking those might now always be the right numbers for the columns everytime plus in the fist column has an empty column heading because each row for that column contains a checkbox so I don't need to sort by anything there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends how the "Edit" or "Delete" is being added to the table. You can either do it before the datatables is initialised by finding the column number(s) and creating your own array to pass as "aTargets", or by removing the icons after-the-fact if all you care about is "look".

The first method requires us seeing your page.
The second method requires knowing what you're using to display the "icons". Standard init? bJQueryUI?

[:contains](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) is your friend

Comment: Well how I have my table set up is just this way: http://pastebin.com/QNimV1F6  or should I be making the table a different way.

Comment: If you're using a static table then what do you mean by "I'm thinking those might now always be the right numbers"? They will be the right numbers until you change them, at which point you'll change the [4,5]. Best bet is to put a comment in the html to remind yourself and do it by hand. Anything else is a performance waste.

Comment: Well I'm just saying because I have pagination coding on its own page and have it included on every table but their might be extra columns on other tables so the numbers won't be the same. Is there a better way to handle all of this. I"m not opposed to reodoing it so that it'll be easier.

Comment: Yes, but the table headers are being defined statically on each page. Adding code to detect which columns you don't want to sort is over-kill. That's like replacing all instances of the number 2 with (1+1) just because you can.

Comment: I guess I'm still not sure what I should do.